# JSON to properties file in java

Tags: java, json, properties, hashmap

We have a json data and we need to convert it into a properteies file to use inside java code as "input.properties" file.Also we are using that input.properties file to supply as input to our main class as HashMap.
  Can anyone explain the process in details with the sample json given below(Expecting properties file structure and hashmap conversion).

```
{
 "process_data": {
    "input": {
        "stockDetails": [{
            "prodName": "bag",
            "Qty": "100"
        }],
        "totalcount": 100
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why the properties file. Why not parse the json and read the data in app?

Comment: Since json is an hierarchy of objects and arrays, unlike property files which are simple key value pairs, there is no simple conversion and you must decide how you want to convert it and write a converter yourself.

Comment: Did you find the solution?